# Application Running as multiple processes

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I have a java/tomcat application running on RedHat linux. Initially when I start the application, everything seems to be working perfectly fine. However, after some time, I guess 1-2 days, I witness the following as the ***top*** output.

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

7023 root      20   0 2857m 577m 5920 S  0.0 14.6   5:12.80 /prd/JAVA//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/prd/myapp

17729 myus     20   0 2875m 574m 5920 S  0.0 14.5  10:49.76 /prd/JAVA//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/prd/myapp

12597 root      20   0 2868m 564m 6304 S  0.0 14.3   5:54.86 /prd/JAVA//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/prd/myapp

15863 myus     20   0 2856m 563m 5936 S  0.0 14.2  10:21.21 /prd/JAVA//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/prd/myapp
```

I'm really confused as to how can my application be running 4 times. For what's worth, it is also taking up memory for all the 4 instances. Please shed some light on this mystery.

Comment: Don't you have any CRON scheduling launching new instances ? Also, I see you have two different users (root & myus) .

Comment: No, I'm not using cron to re-launch the application. And yes, I have 2 users, myus and root. The application is running under myus.

Comment: show us the output of **ps aux | grep java**, also check if the pid file is created for the tomcat process. Let us know how you start your tomcat process, do you have any init script or you launch it using bin/startup.sh script.

Comment: I tried ps aux | grep java and all 4 processes were listed (as expected). I have restarted the application since then and killed those processes....so I can paste the output the next time this issue occurs. As for the startup part, I am using the bin/startup.sh script.